# Webpack React Custom ServiceWorker EVERYTHING not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack, service-worker, workbox

I have attempted to add custom service workers to my Create React App project following this article:

https://medium.com/@chinmaya.cp/custom-service-worker-in-cra-create-react-app-3b401d24b875

However, when building I get a long stretch of errors from the `sw-custom.js` file where everything is not defined (See Image Below):

[image]

Here are my files:

`react-build.js`

```
const workboxBuild = require('workbox-build');

const buildSW = () => {
  // The build is expected to fail if the
  // sw install rules couldn't be generated.
  // Add a catch block to handle this scenario.
  console.log('Building SW');
  return workboxBuild
    .injectManifest({
      swSrc: 'src/sw-custom.js', // custom sw rule

      swDest: 'build/sw.js', // sw output file (auto-generated

      globDirectory: 'build',

      globPatterns: ['**/*.{js,css,html,png,svg}'],

      maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 5 * 1024 * 1024,
    })
    .then(({ count, size, warnings }) => {
      warnings.forEach(console.warn);
      console.info(`${count} files will be precached,
                  totaling ${size / (1024 * 1024)} MBs.`);
    });
};

buildSW();
```

`sw-custom.js`

```
if ('function' === typeof importScripts) {
  importScripts(
    'https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js'
  );

  // Global workbox
  if (workbox) {
    console.log('Workbox is loaded');

    // Disable logging
    workbox.setConfig({ debug: false });

    //`generateSW` and `generateSWString` provide the option
    // to force update an exiting service worker.
    // Since we're using `injectManifest` to build SW,
    // manually overriding the skipWaiting();
    self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
      self.skipWaiting();
      window.location.reload();
      console.log('TESTTESTTEST');
    });

    // Manual injection point for manifest files.
    // All assets under build/ and 5MB sizes are precached.
    workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);

    // Font caching
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      new RegExp('https://fonts.(?:.googlepis|gstatic).com/(.*)'),
      workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'googleapis',
        plugins: [
          new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 30,
          }),
        ],
      })
    );

    // Image caching
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /\.(?:png|gif|jpg|jpeg|svg)$/,
      workbox.strategies.cacheFirst({
        cacheName: 'images',
        plugins: [
          new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 60,
            maxAgeSeconds: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 Days
          }),
        ],
      })
    );

    // JS, CSS caching
    workbox.routing.registerRoute(
      /\.(?:js|css)$/,
      workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
        cacheName: 'static-resources',
        plugins: [
          new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
            maxEntries: 60,
            maxAgeSeconds: 20 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 20 Days
          }),
        ],
      })
    );
  } else {
    console.error('Workbox could not be loaded. No offline support');
  }
}
```

CRA's `sw.js`

```
// register() is not called by default.

// This lets the app load faster on subsequent visits in production, and gives
// it offline capabilities. However, it also means that developers (and users)
// will only see deployed updates on subsequent visits to a page, after all the
// existing tabs open on the page have been closed, since previously cached
// resources are updated in the background.

// To learn more about the benefits of this model and instructions on how to
// opt-in, read [link removed to post on SO]
// This optional code is used to register a service worker.
// register() is not called by default.

const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    // [::1] is the IPv6 localhost address.
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    // 127.0.0.0/8 are considered localhost for IPv4.
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // The URL constructor is available in all browsers that support SW.
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      // Our service worker won't work if PUBLIC_URL is on a different origin
      // from what our page is served on. This might happen if a CDN is used to
      // serve assets; see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2374
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        // This is running on localhost. Let's check if a service worker still exists or not.
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        // Add some additional logging to localhost, pointing developers to the
        // service worker/PWA documentation.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'This web app is being served cache-first by a service ' +
              'worker. To learn more, visit x'
          );
        });
      } else {
        // Is not localhost. Just register service worker
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });

    askNotificationPerms();
  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then((registration) => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              // At this point, the updated precached content has been fetched,
              // but the previous service worker will still serve the older
              // content until all client tabs are closed.
              console.log(
                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                  'tabs for this page are closed. See x'
              );

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              // At this point, everything has been precached.
              // It's the perfect time to display a
              // "Content is cached for offline use." message.
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              // Execute callback
              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  // Check if the service worker can be found. If it can't reload the page.
  fetch(swUrl, {
    headers: { 'Service-Worker': 'script' },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // Ensure service worker exists, and that we really are getting a JS file.
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {
        // No service worker found. Probably a different app. Reload the page.
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then((registration) => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        // Service worker found. Proceed as normal.
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready
      .then((registration) => {
        registration.unregister();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  }
}

export function askNotificationPerms() {
  if ('PushManager' in window) {
    console.log('Push notifications are supported');
  }
}
```

I'm guessing React is trying to compile the custom service worker file when it should just be used by `sw-build.js`

Help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The issue seems to be in your linting rules. you exclude the `sw-build.js` and `sw-custom.js` file from lint and try to run a build?